# Sort array with matched results in first and unmatched results as next in iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, dictionary

```
Input Array:  (
{
    title = "Antonik's BBQ";
},
{
    title = "Jigsaw Salon";
},
{
    title = "London Fish 'N Chips";
},
{
    title = "Kenneth of London";
},

{
    title = "Il Pastaio Fresh Pasta Company";
},
{
    title = "Everett & Jones Barbeque";
},
{
    title = "Duke of Edinburgh";
}
);
```

From the above array, if the search text is "london", I need to sir the array as follows.

```
 Expected sorted array:   (
    {
        title = "Kenneth of London";
    },
    {
        title = "London Fish 'N Chips";
    },

    {
        title = "Antonik's BBQ";
    },
    {
        title = "Jigsaw Salon";
    },
    {
        title = "Il Pastaio Fresh Pasta Company";
    },
    {
        title = "Everett & Jones Barbeque";
    },
    {
        title = "Duke of Edinburgh";
    }
    );
```

I have tried using predicate as follows.

```
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title CONTAINS[cd] %@", _yelpSearchBar.text];
inputArray=[inputArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

But it returns results  which contains "london". Could someone tell me the way to sort it properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could imagine it can be done is manually.  This has been tested:

```
» cat arraysort.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSArray *specialSort(NSArray *array, NSString *searchString)
{
    NSMutableArray *matched = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray *unmatched = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSString *str in array) {
        if ([str rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            [matched addObject:str];
        else
            [unmatched addObject:str];
    }

    return
        [[matched sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:unmatched];
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *arr = @[@"Antonik's BBQ", @"Jigsaw Salon", @"London Fish 'N Chips", @"Kenneth of London", @"Il Pastaio Fresh Pasta Company", @"Everett & Jones Barbeque", @"Duke of Edinburgh"];
        NSArray *sorted = specialSort(arr, @"london");
        NSLog(@"%@", sorted);
    }

    return 0;
}

» ./arraysort
2014-08-08 09:23:41.506 arraysort[81545:507] (
    "Kenneth of London",
    "London Fish 'N Chips",
    "Antonik's BBQ",
    "Jigsaw Salon",
    "Il Pastaio Fresh Pasta Company",
    "Everett & Jones Barbeque",
    "Duke of Edinburgh"
)
 »
```

Comment: -(NSArray *)specialSort:(NSArray *)array WithSearch:(NSString *)searchString{
    NSMutableArray *matched = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray *unmatched = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (YelpLocation *str in array) {
        if ([[str title] caseInsensitiveCompare:searchString] == NSOrderedSame)
            [matched addObject:str];
        else
            [unmatched addObject:str];
    }
    NSMutableArray *resp=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:matched];
    [resp addObjectsFromArray:unmatched];
    return resp;
}  I made changes as above and it's working fine. Thank you.

Comment: @RamChandraReddy OK all bugs fixed and it produces the array you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks good. I checked your program by the following example:

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"Antonik's BBQ", @"Jigsaw Salon", @"London Fish 'N Chips", @"Kenneth of London", @"Il Pastaio Fresh Pasta Company", @"Everett & Jones Barbeque", @"Duke of Edinburgh"];
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"london"];
arr = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

And arr I got:

```
(lldb) po arr
<__NSArrayI 0x10d599a50>(
London Fish 'N Chips,
Kenneth of London
)
```

The only difference I did was change `title` to `self` and strings directly in an array.

Comment: Hi Szu, This is not the expected output.I made changes to Droppy's code and it's working fine. Thank you.